# C program to set MSB and LSB of a number

Tags: c

I have to write a C program which returns ‘S’, if both LSB and MSB of a number are set, returns ‘R’, if both LSB and MSB of number are not set, returns ‘L’ if LSB is set but not the MSB and returns ‘M’ if MSB is set but not the LSB. Here I have made a program to set only LSB but i have problem with another logic. Please help me with this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

char result;   
char set_reset(unsigned int number)
{

    if(number & 1)

    result='L';


    return result;  // Do not change the return
}

 int main (void)
{
    char result_value;
    result_value = set_reset(150); // it should return 'M'
    result_value = set_reset(11); // it should return 'L'
    result_value = set_reset(171); // it should return 'S'
    result_value = set_reset(42); // it should return 'R'

}
```

Comment: _"i have problem with another logic"_ is very unclear. You have no question here. What are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you have a problem with your function definition. Your code expects a `unsigned int` but in `main` you write that `171` shall result in `S` (i.e. both MSB and LSB set). That will not happen as an `unsigned int` is more than 8 bits.

So my guess is that you want:

```
char set_reset(unsigned char number)
                        ^^^^
```

In that case your program could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

char set_reset(unsigned char number)
{
    unsigned int lsb = number & 1;
    unsigned int msb = number & (1 << (CHAR_BIT-1));

    if (lsb && msb) return 'S';
    if (lsb) return 'L';
    if (msb) return 'M';
    return 'R';
}

 int main (void)
{
    printf("%c\n", set_reset(150));
    printf("%c\n", set_reset(11));
    printf("%c\n", set_reset(171));
    printf("%c\n", set_reset(42));

}
```

Output:

```
M
L
S
R
```

Notice that CHAR_BIT from limits.h is the number of bits in a char. Normally it is 8 but that is not guaranteed. Therefore it is better to take it from limits.h